# How to detect scale and pan gesture in an AndroidView or UiKitView in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, uikit, android-view, gesture

I'm using [flutter_pdfview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pdfview) to display a PDF in my
Flutter App. Under the hood, the PDFView widget uses an [AndroidView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AndroidView-class.html) or a [UiKitView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/UiKitView-class.html) depending on the platform.
I would like to get the coordinates of a tap event relatively to the PDF document knowing that a user can zoom and pan on the PDF.
For this, I would need to subscribe to scale and pan events in order to know which part of the document is currently displayed on the screen. Then I could figure out where exactly the user taps.

I've tried passing my own `ScaleGestureRecognizer` and `PanGestureRecognizer`. Unfortunately, the `onUpdate()`, `onStart()` never seem to be triggered.

Here's my code:

```dart
class PDFViewer extends StatelessWidget {
  PDFViewer({this.filePath});

  final String filePath;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final scale = ScaleGestureRecognizer()
      ..onUpdate = (details) {
        print(details.scale);
      };
    final pan = PanGestureRecognizer()
      ..onUpdate = (details) {
        print(details.delta);
      }
      ..onStart = (_) {
        print('Start pan');
      }
      ..onEnd = (_) {
        print('End pan');
      };

    return PDFView(
      filePath: filePath,
      gestureRecognizers: <Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>>{
        Factory<ScaleGestureRecognizer>(() => scale),
        Factory<PanGestureRecognizer>(() => pan),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: not an answer but checkout pdf package from pub

Comment: [pdf](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) is made to create PDF documents but not to view them

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for the issue. I was checking for the presense of onTapDown and added

```
gestureRecognizers: Set()
        ..add(Factory<TapGestureRecognizer>(() => TapGestureRecognizer()
          ..onTapDown = (tap) {
            print("hell bro");
          })),
```

But, it didn't work somehow. I was checking for other solutions and thought to add GestureDetector and detect tap from that.

So, I just wrapped PDFView with a GestureDetector. Surprisingly, gestureRecognizers inside PDFView worked after adding GestureDetector() Widget. Since I was checking for onTapDown event with gestureRecognizers, I added onTap parameter in GestureDetector.

My Widget looked like this:

```
GestureDetector(
    onTap: (){}, //This has to be added. Won't work without this.
    child: PDFView(
      filePath: widget.link,
      onError: (error) {
        print(error.toString());
      },
      onPageError: (page, error) {
        print('$page: ${error.toString()}');
      },
      onViewCreated: (PDFViewController pdfViewController) {
        pdfController=pdfViewController;
      },
      onPageChanged: (a, b){
        visible=false;
      },
      gestureRecognizers: Set()
        ..add(Factory<TapGestureRecognizer>(() => TapGestureRecognizer()
          ..onTapDown = (tap) {
            print("Tap Down Gesture Detected");
          })),
    ),
  )
```

So, for your case I guess you'll have to add the following code:

```
return GestureDetector(
            onScaleStart: (a){}, //This has to be added. Won't work without this.
            onPanStart: (a){}, //This has to be added. Won't work without this.
            child: PDFView(
              filePath: filePath,
              gestureRecognizers: Set()
                ..add(
                    Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(() => scale)
                )
                ..add(
                Factory<OneSequenceGestureRecognizer>(() => pan),
            ),)
          );
```